# How to prevent append parameter in 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using this redirect command in .htaacess file.

```
Redirect 301 /old-path.html /new-path.html
```

It shows me `/new-path.html?page=old-path`

Probability, appended parameter is result of some RewriteRule and RewiteCond in my htaccess.

I don't like to edit my original htaccess codes.

I found below command is very close to the result.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /old-path.html /new-path.html?
```

The result is `/new-path.html?`  which has only an extra **?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `RedirectMatch` because it doesn't have a way to discard old/previous query string.

It is better to use a `RewriteRule` like this:

```sh
RewriteRule ^old-path\.html$ /new-path.html? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Trailing `?` in target will discard any query string.

On Apache 2.4+ you can also use:

```sh
RewriteRule ^old-path\.html$ /new-path.html [L,R=301,NC,QSD]
```

As a thumb rule place all `R=...` rules **on top of your** .htaccess before other rules. This will make these rules work before other internal rewrite rules that may modify request URI or query string.